# Tool to extract text from HTML

Tags: html, scraping

Having a website, I'd like to extract content from it. So far I've been using Regex in Notepad++, but

1. we all know [we should not use Regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4136325)
2. due to a redesign of the website, getting the Regex right is almost impossible

I have read about possible answers [1](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/9973/9295), [2](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/19622/9295), [3](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1986/9295) and [4](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/13274/9295) but they all boil down to Python+Scrapy or JSoup.

1. I'm looking for a tool for **non-programmers** which
2. allows the user to select elements **visually** (not necessarily in rendered HTML, could also be in HTML source)
3. constructs a list of "XPaths" (or similar, XML XPath understanding is available)
4. can later re-run the extraction without GUI in a scheduled job

Other requirements

1. Windows or Ubuntu
2. commercial solution is ok

Answer (score -1):

> tool for non-programmers
>
> constructs a list of "XPaths"

Almost contradictive requirements, yet still soome prominent scraping software are good in both. See the list of them:

- [Content Grabber](http://scraping.pro/content-grabber-review/) - rerun a project as an standalone scraping agent.
- [CloudScrape](http://scraping.pro/cloudscrape-review/) - rerun thru API
- [Helium Scraper](http://scraping.pro/helium-scraper-review/) - schedule through Windows Task Scheduler
- [Screen Scraper](http://scraping.pro/screen-scraper-review/) - schedule through Windows Task Scheduler
- [Web Content Extractor](http://scraping.pro/web-content-extractor-review/) - schedule through Windows Task Scheduler

Their [short descriptions](http://scraping.pro/software-for-web-scraping/).

Comment: Welcome on Software Recommendations. One of the rules here is that you should have experience with the tools you suggest. Another rules is that you should mention how the software fulfills the requirements. Do all of them provide a XPath-like language and provide a command line tool to re-run the extract?

Comment: Lists of answers without a detailed description of the product are generally frowned upon. Might want to check out [What is required for an answer to be high quality?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality)

Comment: @Thomas, I've updated according to your comment.

Comment: CloudScrape is a web-service, not an application. "Everything in the cloud"

Comment: @Thomas, true; yet it matches all the other criterias...